# Nothing happened when I tried to echo data from join table in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, html-table

My model :

```
public function category($cat)
{
    $this->db->select('c.id, c.cat2, c.category, m.id, m.date, m.when_date, m.when_time, m.where_m');
    $this->db->from('category c');
    $this->db->where('c.category', '$cat');
    $this->db->join('meeting m', 'm.id_cat = c.id');
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result->result();
}
```

My controller:

```
    $data['meeting'] = $this->users_m->category($cat);
    $this->load->view('category', $data);
```

My view:

```
<table> 
<?php foreach($meeting as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo ($row->id); ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo ($row->id_cat); ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo ($row->date); ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo ($row->when_date); ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo ($row->where_m); ?></td>
    </tr> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

And nothing happend while I try to echo this data; no error message nothing. Any idea? I'm new in this.

Comment: use `$this->db->last_query()` to find what sql query is being executed ...

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\models\users_m.php on line 23

Comment: which line is no 23 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where clause could be the problem. You wrote:`

```
$this->db->where('c.category', '$cat');
```

I think it should look something like:

```
$this->db->where('c.category', $cat);
```

(without the single quotes)

So the query is comparing the category to the string $cat. I guess this won't be in your database. So the result will be empty.

Comment: he posted the error message in comment ..please check.

Comment: I checked the comment and i knew that this could cause the problem ;),
no problem :)